# JQGRID not loading next page even when it contains data

Tags: php, jquery, html, jqgrid

The jqgrid is showing correctly the total no of records and also the page no but not moving to next page. On clicking next page it shows loading but remains on the same page. I have seen many previous post related to this but did not get any solutions.I have tried #pager but it is also not working. Actually i am not able to understand how this jqgrid actually works.The image below shows the jqgrid with the all the records and page but not moving to next page.

[image: jqgrid results page]

Here is my code.

```html
<?php require_once 'templates/header.php';?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-custom.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css"/>
<style>
.ui-widget{font-family:Arial; color:#fff;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hdiv {height:25px;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-pager {height:40px;}
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
  background: #fff !important;font-weight: bold;color:#000;font-size:13px;;}
.ui-widget-content{border: 1px solid #ddd !important;}
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td{height: 33px !important;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div, .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th,.ui-jqgrid-hdiv{height: 33px !important;}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-resize-ltr{margin: 0px !important;}
#pager2{height: 36px !important;}
input.ui-pg-input {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    height: 33.5px !important;
    margin: 0;
    min-width:50px;
    width:80px !important;
}
.ui-th-column{padding-top:10px !important; }
</style>
<div class="content">
 <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <h1 class="text_underline">Quiz Results: </h1>
   <br/>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
        <table id="list2"></table> 
    <div id="pager2" ></div>
   </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-custom.min.js"></script>
<script src='js/grid.locale-en.js'></script>
<script src='js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js'></script>
<script>
    jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({ 
    url:'server.php', 
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "GET",
    colNames:['Quiz No','Category Name', 'Right Answer', 'Wrong Answer','Unanswered'], 
    colModel:[ {name:'id',index:'id', align:"center"}, 
    {name:'category_name',index:'category_name', align:"center"}, 
    {name:'right_answer',index:'right_answer', align:"center"},
    {name:'wrong_answer',index:'wrong_answer', align:"center"},
       {name:'unanswered',index:'unanswered', align:"center"}    
    ],
    rowNum:10, 
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    gridview:true, 
    pager:'#pager2', 
    sortname: 'id', 
    recordpos: 'left',
    viewrecords: true, 
    sortorder: "asc", 
    height: '100%'
    });
    
    
 </script>
 
<?php require_once 'templates/footer.php';?>
```

```html
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once 'config.php';

 $db = new Cl_DBclass();
 $user_id = $_SESSION['id'];
 
 $page = $_GET['page']; // get the requested page
 $limit =$_GET['rows']; // get how many rows we want to have into the grid
 $sidx = $_GET['sidx']; // get index row - i.e. user click to sort
 $sord = $_GET['sord']; // get the direction
 if(!$sidx) $sidx =1; // connect to the database
 $result = sqlsrv_query( $db->con, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM scores where user_id = '$user_id' ");
 $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
 $count = $row['count'];
 
 if( $count >0 ) { 
 $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit);
 //$total_pages = ceil($count/1);
 } else {
 $total_pages = 0; 
 } if ($page > $total_pages) 
 $page=$total_pages; 
 $start = $limit*$page - $limit; // do not put $limit*($page - 1) 
 $SQL = "SELECT S.*, C.category_name from scores S  LEFT JOIN categories C ON S.category_id = C.id where S.user_id = '5'
   ORDER BY $sidx $sord
   OFFSET  $start ROWS 
   FETCH NEXT $limit-$start ROWS ONLY ";
 $result = sqlsrv_query( $db->con, $SQL ) or die("Couldn t execute query.".sqlsrv_errors($db->con));
 $responce = new stdClass();
 $responce->page = $page;
 $responce->total = $total_pages;
 $responce->records = $count; 
 $i=0;
 while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
 $responce->rows[$i]['id']=$row['id'];
 $responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array($row['id'],$row['category_name'],$row['right_answer'],$row['wrong_answer'],$row['unanswered']); $i++; 
 } 
 echo json_encode($responce);exit;
```

[server response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VSML.png)

Comment: I think that your problem is in server side code. Please use the debugger console of Chrome or FireFox to see the server response from the server when you move to the next page.  It will show you the problem

Comment: ok i will trythis

Comment: i have seen debugger console and i get many errors like this "Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.". I have seen some post regarding it but they say it is firefox browser problem but when i run in google chrome also it doesn't work either

Comment: Hello, You should look at the response. Click on the response tab to see what is returned from server after you try to go to next page

Comment: i have added another pic and in bottom i think they are server responses. Are they what you are talking about.

Comment: Yes, that is. Look where the file server.php is and expand it (the triangle at left) to see the response after make a click to the next page.